# cordova javascript - declare class using variable

Tags: javascript, cordova

I try to declare the hsbc class in my cordova web view app.
It is work on pc with chrome, but not working on my android phone.

```
function(bank) {
  // show
  alert('test1');

  // Not Working
  var bank_class = new Function('return new ' + bank)();

  // Not working
  var bank_class2 = new window[bank]();

  // Not show on my phone
  alert('test2');
}
```

---

agency.js

```
class Agency {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {};
  }
}
```

---

hsbc.js

```
class Hsbc extends Agency {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.code = 'Hsbc';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details on how is it not working? Any error logs? What browser and model are you trying to run this code on?

Comment: I am using a device which is Redmi Note 4X, and the default browser is chrome (latest version).

Comment: @Kase class is a reserve keyword in javascript. You cannot use it for variable. better assign any other name

Comment: @front_end_dev i edited the post again, please see my code again.

Comment: Share working example as jsFiddle demo.